# Apple AppStore app localization

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

Not sure where to put this.

I have a question about localization of an app. We have created an app that is available in Slovenia an Croatia. The app itself is localized. While Google play enables us to show different texts based on language, the Apple App store does not. The reason is tha both Stores (Slovenian an Croatian) are using English (U.K.).

Is it possible to set different texts and screenshots for different territories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App Store pages are managed via iTunes Connect. The current list of possible translations of your app's description, metadata and screenshots are: (All other "stores" show the Default language; there is no way to localize the App Store page for them)

[image]

Source:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/AppStoreTerritories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH18-SW3

Comment: Thank you for your response. The workaround we are going to be using is translating all text to English and say that the app is available in Slovenian and Croatian language. But Apple will have to find a solution of this problem, because i suspect we are not the only ones having this kind of problems.

Comment: Valid point, I think the localisations of the app itself are also shown on the store: http://imgur.com/a/gnZvs

Comment: They replied and asked me to provid them with my feedback on https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/wa/jumpTo?page=contactUs&contactfaq=feedback to have those languages added. I am jet to recieve their response.

Answer (score -1):

Are you asking how to set the test in the app for each region or for the app store?

I would try creating localized string folders set for the English language and the countries of Slovenia and Croatia.  I would try the following folder names

**en_SI.lproj** for Slovenia

**en_HR.lproj** for Croatia

With those folders, you can put your Localized.strings file for each region.

For the App store, you may be limited.  The App Store supports fewer languages and regions than the apps do.